# Create bom.xml file using Jenkins

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

In my situation, I have on perm configured [dependencytrack](https://dependencytrack.org/) in my location. what im going do is, in the ci process via Jenkins need to scan dependency on a python project. I used free style project and give a shell script to execute in the build. once it done it will create bom.xml file. once i pass this bom.xml file to [cyclonedx-bom](https://pypi.org/project/cyclonedx-bom/) it will return following error in Jenkins job.

In Jenkins job:-

```
[DependencyTrack] Either the projectId or the projectName and projectVersion have to be specified
ERROR: Step ‘Publish BOM to Dependency-Track’ failed: Either the projectId or the projectName and projectVersion have to be specified
```

Can somebody help me out to reslove this issue?